# responsive image height and width % for scaling?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

A user can create an inspiration via uploading an image or entering text.

**view**

```
<% if inspiration.image.present? %>
  <div class="inspiration-image">
    <%= link_to image_tag(inspiration.image.url(:medium)), inspiration %>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <%= inspiration.name %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**css**

```
// for images
.inspiration-image {
  display: inline;
  img {
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 2.5px;
    margin-bottom: 2.5px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 164px;
  }
}

// for text
.panel-default {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 40%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #446CB3;
    border-radius: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border: 2.5px white solid;
}

//for text
.panel-body {
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 12px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}
```

Looks good with a set height:

[image]

But if the users increases or decreases screen size then a white gap develops for images, which is what I'd like to avoid with your help:

[image]

### UPDATE BASED UPON PASCAL'S QUESTION

view

```
<% if inspiration.image.present? %>
  <div class="panel panel-default" id="conditions">
    <div class="panel-body">
    </div>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="white-link"><%= inspiration.name %></div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

css

```
#conditions {
  background-image: url('goal-setting-conditions.jpeg'); # instead of this image, which I just used to test if it works, how can I make the image reflect whatever inspiration it is: <%= link_to image_tag(inspiration.image.url(:medium)), inspiration %>
  background-size: cover;
}
```

This is the sort of behavior I was hoping for where no matter screen size image and text-boxes width and height equal each other:

[image]

Comment: Can you place the picture in a  `background-image`? In that case you could use `background-size: cover;`

Comment: Why this is tagged with ruby and ruby-on-rails?

Comment: @WandMaker look at the view. I'm using ruby on rails to generate the panels

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com Will the answer have anything to do with Ruby or Rails?

Comment: Good point @WandMaker. I thought a person would need some ruby on rails background to fully grasp question. You want me to take the ruby tag out?

Comment: This is just a matter of CSS or even javascript if we dare to go that way ;-) The way you generate the view doesn't really matter. :)

Comment: Updated question @PascalGoldbach based upon your insightful question :)

Comment: Yea just struggling with the ruby part. I updated question with furthur explanation @Stan :)

Comment: There could be a ruby or a RoR solution, but since *ruby-on-rails* implies that ruby, you could remove the former.  Tagging is what the question is concerning, but also who is being targeted.  There may be some ruby programmers that don't do anything rails and, although unadvised, this answer could potentially be solved with only ruby logic.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to get add the image as a background in the parent div.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.inspiration-image').find('img').each(function(n, image) {
        var image = jQuery(image);
        var thisurl = jQuery(this).attr('src');
        image.parents('.inspiration-image').css('background-image', 'url(' + thisurl + ')');
    });
});
```

In CSS set the `background-size` on the `div` to cover. Hide the image in the container.

```
.inspiration-image {background-size:cover;}
.inspiration-image img{opacity:0;}
```

Comment: Instead of using jQuery you can also just add the background image in directly.

Comment: The problem with the jquery is it doesn't make the image equal the same width and height as the textboxes. Sorry I could have explained better in question and will do so now.

Comment: Updated question Martin :)